Apache Beam - Load a single file to PCollection
This may be a very simple question, but a clarification would be really appreciated. I have a multi-GB CSV input file (a single file), and I am loading the contents into a PCollection using TextIO. Do you think this file read will be distributed among multiple worker nodes, considering the fact that it is a single file? I was thinking that, unless we supply multiple split files, reading will be performed in a single worker node.

Please read tag descriptors before using a tag.

It should load the file in parallel since the source is splittable.
